# Deleting and Merging Snapshots in RTC

Tags: rtc, ibm-jazz

I have 2 stream, one main (mnt) and one patch stream (4.5_patch). I had created a snapshot on 4.5_patch as 4.6_patch_snap. I then deleted the 4.5_patch stream, it gave me a warning of content being deleted and asked for me to merge the snapshots with some other stream. Then I chose, mnt stream for merging and deleted the 4.5_patch stream. The 4.6_patch_snap is now showing in mnt stream. Basically wanted to merge the 2 streams.

Does the mnt stream would have all the changes that were done on 4.6_patch_snap from 4.5_patch stream?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Basically wanted to merge the 2 streams": which two streams? You only have one left: mnt.

Comment: I wanted to merge 4.5_patch Stream with mnt. So I deleted the 4.5_patch stream thinging that with the snapshots, all the code, will also get transferred.

Comment: Yes, but since you have deleted 4.5_patch, you now have only mnt stream, no?

Comment: Yes. So deleting means that the deleted stream gets merged with the main one?

Comment: Exactly: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then deleted the 4.5_patch stream, it gave me a warning of content being deleted and asked for me to merge the snapshots with some other stream.
>
> **Then I chose, mnt stream for merging and deleted the 4.5_patch stream**.

That is when you merged  `4.5_patch` stream to `mnt`.

> The 4.6_patch_snap is now showing in `mnt` stream

The 4.6_patch_snap is the result of that merge.

> Basically wanted to merge the 2 streams.

Too late: you already did.

Comment: Does this mean that all the code changes done would also get merged?

Comment: @Surmeet all the changeset from 4.5 have been merged to mnt, and the result is the 4.6 snapshot.